# Problemas al almacenar una propiedad con un [(NgModel)] input

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la que el usuario de la app selecciona una mesa, y seguido a ello, selecciona los productos que (en un flijo real) los clientes ordenen, todo bien hasta cuando me selecciona los productos, una vez seleccionados en tiempo real me van apareciendo a mi lado derecho de un modal en tipo lista, donde se debe de registrar la cantidad de productos (Así como muestro en la siguiente imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si notan, en donde está el listado de productos todos tienen el mismo numero, cada que cambio cualquiera de esos campos se me cambia en todos y no debe de ser así

mi codigo HTML (especificamente de la sesión de la lista) es el siguiente:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="title">Products to set</div>
                        <div class="container-products" *ngFor="let products of selectedProducts; let i = index">
                            <div class="products-quantity-section">
                                <div for="" class="product-name">{{products}} :</div>
                                <div class="quantity-input">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="1"
                                        [(ngModel)]="quantity" name="quantity">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

y mi ts es este:

```
setProductInTable(tableId: any) {
console.log(this.selectedProducts)
// console.log(tableId)

this.selectedProducts.forEach(product => {
  console.log(this.quantity)
  let orderDetail = {
    order_date: new Date(),
    order_details: product,
    quantity: this.quantity,
  };
  console.log(this.order.quantity)

  console.log(orderDetail)

  this.orderService.createOrder(tableId, orderDetail).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`quantity` es la misma variable/propiedad para todos los inputs dentro del *ngFor, si cada elemento de `selectedProducts` tiene la propiedad quantity, deberías usar `products.quantity` para que así se haga *bind* al quantity de cada selectedProduct.

Eso es lo que puedo ver con la información del código que nos brindas.
Saludos.